# Persist into onFlush Symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, persist

I'm trying to persist into onFlush event listener but I have this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO logs (dateSauvegarde, montantProvision, montantPrecedant, commentaire, dateCreation, dateModification, idProfil, idSinistre) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)':
>
> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound

But.. these field are well filled...

```
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args){
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    $session = new Session();
    $loggedContact = $session->get('loggedContact');


    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof ApcSinistres) {
            $changements = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
            foreach($changements as $colonne => $changement){

                if($colonne == "provisions"){
                    $logs = new ApcSauvegardeProvisionsHistorisation();
                    $logs->setDatesauvegarde(new DateTime());
                    $logs->setIdprofil($loggedContact);
                    $logs->setIdsinistre($entity);
                    $logs->setCommentaire("Recalcul des provisions suite au changement du statut du sinistre");
                    $logs->setMontantprovision($changement[1]);
                    $logs->setMontantprecedent($changement[0]);

                    $uow->persist($logs );
                }

            }
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

I don't know why I have this error, does someone have a solution ?

Regards

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($logs);` before the persist?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the changeset for your `ApcSauvegardeProvisionsHistorisation` object manually if you want to persist something within `onFlush`. The reason for that is changesets were already calculated before `onFlush` is called.

```
$logMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(ApcSauvegardeProvisionsHistorisation::class);
// ...
$em->persist($logs);
$uow->computeChangeSet($logMetadata, $logs);
```